# Do I need to use CSRF tokens in a cookie-based API?

Tags: security, next.js, csrf, next-auth

I have an API in Next.js (NextAuth.js) that only the frontend will be using. It uses cookies for authentication. My question is could a malicious website change the user's data using CSRF? Should I implement CSRF tokens or can I prevent malicious websites from changing the data without it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If authentication is based on something that the browser sends automatically with requests (like cookies), then yes, you most likely need protection against CSRF.

You can try it yourself: set up a server on one origin (eg. localhost:3000), and an attacker page on another (eg. localhost:8080, it's the same as a different domain, controlled by an attacker). Now log in to your app on :3000, and on your attacker origin make a page that will post to :3000 something that changes data. You will see that while :8080 will not receive the response (because of the same origin policy), :3000 will indeed receive and process the request. It will also receive cookies set for :3000, regardless of where the user is making the request from.

For mitigation, you can implement the synchronizer token pattern (csrf tokens), double submit, or you can decide to rely on the SameSite property of cookies, which are not supported by old browsers, but are supported by fairly recent ones, so there is some risk, depending on who your users are.

Comment: A good answer. It's worth mentioning that SameSite cookies do not protect against subdomain hijacking because they are based on the "registerable domain" concept.

Comment: So do you mean, for example, if I deployed the app on Heroku where the free subdomains end with .herokuapp.com another attacker could bypass SameSite restriction by also deploying their website on Heroku to make the browser think it is the same website?